# <a> tag will not work in firefox, only in IE

Tags: html

the following html will only work in IE, but not in firefox. Can anyone see why? Thanks

```
<a href="../homepage.aspx" id="aHomepage">
                        <td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">Home</td>

                    </a>
```

Comment: I can see why. It's horribly invalid HTML.

Comment: thanks for the constructive criticism and trying to help me fix an inherited mess.

Answer (score 3):

Put the `<a>` inside of your table cell.

```
<td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="../homepage.aspx" id="aHomepage">Home</a></td>
```

If you want the entire cell to be a link use CSS to make the `<a>` fill the cell or use JavaScript to make the whole cell respond to an onclick event.

Comment: This works, but the issue is I want the class to affect the text - the class is changed by the vb code behind depending which page is selected. when doing this in this way, the css class does not apply its changes to the link text.

Comment: @njj56- What is your css that you are trying to apply?

Comment: I was looking into just creating an onclick even, but the problem is i use the following code to get the leading section for the href : <%=Depth%> - I need to be able to get the depth from the pages that call this (this is a header) - but can not figure out how to do so.

Comment: depending on the page, this is the css 
.Tab_White
   {
    background-position: center top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    background-image: url('images/Tab_White.gif');
    cursor: hand;
    color: #084A84;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana
   }
  .Tab_Blue
   {
    background-position: center top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    background-image: url('images/Tab_Blue.gif');
    cursor: hand;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana
   }

Comment: basically, i need a way to in the vb back end to be able to change the class of the <a> or i need a way in html to get the value of <%=Depth%> so it can be passed into a javascript function. Every time I add "<%=Depth%>" inside the passing parameters of the JS call, I then get errors in this pages code behind stating that td is not declaired and may be due to its protection level - i cant use runat="server" in both the td and a tags.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in FF because that is bad markup. Don't ever wrap td's with anchors. Browsers will try to interpret your html as best as it can. You are lucky that IE decided to play nice this time. Instead do this:

```
 <td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">
     <a href="../homepage.aspx" id="aHomepage">Home</a>
  </td>
```

To make the anchor the size of the `<TD>` use some css like this:

```
td a{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Anchors are inline elements, which do not have height. To make it respect height make it `display: inline-block` so it stays inline but respects `height` and `width` like a block level element.

Edit:
One way of passing that depth variable would be to set a property on the anchor and getting that with the click event:

```
<a href="../homepage.aspx" id="aHomepage" depth='100'>Home</a>
```

Then you can use js to get the value (roughly this way as I don't know how your events are set up):

```
$("a").click(function(){
   this.getAttribute("depth");
});
```

Sorry I don't have the VB code to add it to the anchor.

Comment: @njj56: Where does your code behind place the class that dictates the styling you want on the text? If it is on the TD you can just change your css a little by adding .Tab_White a{/*styles here */}

Comment: sorry, not sure exactly what you are asking by this comment. - i can use the code as above which you have stated, but i need to find a way to style the link differently depending which page is hit - currently in codebehind i used something like what is below to change the style but I can't do this for the <a> since i can not use runat="server" twice -                __                                                  If Section = 0 Then
            td0_a.Attributes.Add("lock", "true")
            td0_a.Attributes.Add("class", "Tab_Blue")
End If

Comment: trying to use an embedded code block to set the property in the TD, if so, from the onclick i can call the javascript function, then pull this using get attribute in the function.

Comment: You said your css was defined as .Tab_White{} but it wasn't affecting the text when the anchor was wrapped by the td. To make your css affect the anchors you need to make it more specific to the anchor. Right now it looks like your code is adding the class to the td. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ApnAR/5/ for what I am talking about css wise. It also shows a way to edit the class names using jquery